# How to Calculate area under a smoothed line

Tags: r, curve-fitting, smoothing

I recently asked a question about how to calculate an area under a curve here:

[How to calculate the area under each end of a sine curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496103/how-to-calculate-the-area-under-each-end-of-a-sine-curve)

And I received some good answers, which all involved the predict function being used on a linear regression model. Now I'd like to calculate a similar Area Under a Curve, but the line forming the curve is a simple smoothed fit (not based on any kind of regression analysis).

So given a dataset:

```
y<-c(-13,16,35,40,28,36,43,33,40,33,22,-5,-27,-31,-29,-25,-26,-31,-26,-24,-25,-29,-23,4)
t<-1:24
```

I'd like to fit a smoothed line to my data (mean of 2 points above and below) like so:

```
Smooth<-as.vector(filter(y,filter=rep(1,4))/4)

#I don't want to loose my first and last data points, so I cheat and add them back in.
Check<-data.frame(y,Smooth)
Smooth2<-ifelse(is.na(Check$Smooth),y, Check$Smooth)


plot(t,y)
abline(h=0,lty=2)
lines(t,Smooth2)
```

Next, I want to calculate the area under the positive curve, as well as the area under the negative curve. I assume this would involve finding the 3 roots (where the line passes through zero), to delineate where the positive curve starts and stops, and the negative curve starts and stops.

Comment: Just use something like `approxfun` rather than `predict` to get a function to predict `y` values for every `x`: `f<-approxfun(t,Smooth2)`. This question really isn't any different

Comment: Agree with @MrFlick: It's nothing special with this smoothing function. You can just run: `library(MESS) ; auc(t, pmax(Smooth2, 0))` for the positive area and `auc(t, pmin(Smooth2,0))` for the negative.