# Plotting fitted and original data in R, with higher density of x values for fitted

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I tried searching around here for a while now but I didn't really find any solution to my problem. I want an easy way to get to the equation of a fitted model and display it together with my original data.

here is the code that worked so far:

```
#the dataframe:
library(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame(x=c(0,3,5,7,9,14),y=c(1.7,25.4,185.5,303.9,255.9,0.0))

#fitting a third degree polinomial model
fit1<- lm(y~poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE),data = df)

#plotting fitted and original values
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(x, y=predict(fit1)), col=2)
```

The following plot results [red = predicted values, black = original data]:

[image: red = predicted values, black = original data]

Now, I tried to get a better grip on what the model actually looked like compared to my original data points, as I want to calculate the area under the line later.

I tried by extracting the coefficients from fit1 by calling

```
coef(fit1)
```

and typing in the approximate coefficients in an equation

```
x1<-seq(0:14)
eq<- 20.35*x1+6.64*x1^2-0.58*x1^3-10.84
```

is there any easier way to  "extract" an f(x) = x+x^2+c etc. function from a model and displaying it with high density (infinite x values between 0 and 14) together with the original values? Maybe using geom_line() or stat_function()?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Nice and well presented question, if only all first-timers explained things this clearly. By the way, the relevant documentation (for `predict()`) is a bit hidden, but you can find it with `?predict.lm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is not to predict on the data which you used to make the model but to generate a denser data in the same range:

```
x <- seq(from = min(df$x), to = max(df$x), by = 0.1)
```

Here is the full code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 14), y = c(1.7, 25.4, 185.5, 303.9, 255.9, 0.0))
fit1 <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE), data = df)
```

Generate dense data:

```
predf <-  data.frame(x = seq(from = min(df$x), to = max(df$x), by = 0.1))
```

Predict y on the dense data:

```
predf$y <- predict(fit1, predf)
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(data= predf, aes(x, y  ), col=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I found some very good code here: [How to calculate the area under each end of a sine curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496103/how-to-calculate-the-area-under-each-end-of-a-sine-curve)
to extract the function and calculate the AUC and adapted it to the example here:

```
 #get the function from the model
poly3fnct <- function(x){
  (fnct <- fit1$coeff[1]+
     fit1$coeff[2]* x +
     fit1$coeff[3]* x^2 +
     fit1$coeff[4]* x^3) +
    return(fnct)
}

#function to find the roots
manyroots <- function(f,inter){
  roots <- array(NA, inter)
  for(i in 1:(length(inter)-1)){
    roots[i] <- tryCatch({
      return_value <- uniroot(f,c(inter[i],inter[i+1]))$root
    }, error = function(err) {
      return_value <- -1
    })
  }
  retroots <- roots[-which(roots==-1)]
  return(retroots)
}
#find the roots or x values for y = 0
roots <- manyroots(poly3fnct,seq(0,14))
roots

#integrate function
integrate(poly3fnct, roots[1],roots[2])
```